# How to make working hours in ruby ​on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm creating a chat panel with a bot. Every message sent by the bot will depend on working hours. For example, during business hours the customer sends a message to the bot and the bot will reply to the text message with the sentence: `Hello, you sent a message during business hours`
and for example when outside working hours the customer sends a text message to the bot and the bot will reply to the message with the sentence: `Hello, you sent a message outside of working hours`. Where working hours apply every Monday-Saturday at 08: 30-17: 00.

I made a configuration using an array like this:

```
start_on =  [
  "Monday, 08:30:00",
  "Tuesday, 08:30:00",
  "Wednesday, 08:30:00",
  "Thursday, 08:30:00",
  "Friday, 08:30:00",
  "Saturday, 08:30:00"
]
end_on =  [
  "Monday, 17:00:00",
  "Tuesday, 17:00:00",
  "Wednesday, 17:00:00",
  "Thursday, 17:00:00",
  "Friday, 17:00:00",
  "Saturday, 17:00:00"
]
```

And what I want to ask is how to set the current time `current_time = (Time.now.to_time)` by configuring the working hours in the array start_on and end_on using ruby ​​on rails?

Comment: Your last sentence, while not clear to me, seems to suggest you want to solve the problem in a particular way. It seems to me, however, that you should be asking how to construct a method having an argument that is either a string or `Time` instance, that returns `true` or `fase`, depending on whether that time is within business hours. @Luskmo has provided such a method below. Focusing on the trees rather than the forest in this way is sometimes referred to as the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 4):

This function returns true if the day is not sunday and the time is between 08:30 and 17:00

```
  def is_working_hour?(time)
   !time.sunday? && time.to_s(:time).between?('08:30','17:00')
  end

 is_working_hour?(Time.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally structure the start and end times like this using [wday](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-wday) as the day of the week (0 is sunday so 1 == monday):

```rb
times = [
  { day: 1, start: "08:30:00", end: "17:00:00" },
  { day: 2, start: "08:30:00", end: "17:00:00" },
  ...
]
```

Once you've got a structure like this (you can work it work it out from the above too of course), you can use the following to get *today's times*.

```rb
today = times.detect { |time| time[:day] == Time.now.wday }
```

Then start and end times are just:

```rb
start_time = Time.parse(today[:start])
end_time = Time.parse(today[:end])
# start_time = Time.parse("08:30:00")
# end_time = Time.parse("17:00:00")
```

Then it's simply a matter of seeing if the current time is inside that range:

```rb
 Time.now > start && Time.now < end_time
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the values in DateTime, you have to `strptime` the weekday for Date, and the time for the Time. Then combine the resulting date and time to obtain the DateTime.

```
curr_index=1 #loop index if necessary

#get start datetime
arr=start_on[curr_index].split(",")
d = Date.strptime(arr[0].strip, '%A')
t = Time.strptime(arr[1].strip, ' %T')
startime = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, t.zone)

#get end datetime
arr=end_on[curr_index].split(",")
d = Date.strptime(arr[0].strip, '%A')
t = Time.strptime(arr[1].strip, ' %T')
endtime = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, t.zone)

return (startime..endtime).cover? Time.now #check if within the range
```